How to find the hyperbolic line segment that is perpendicular to two hyperbolic lines in space?
A hyperbolic line is uniquely determined by its two ideal points (at each end of the line), which can be any two distinct points on the sphere at infinity. Let there be given two hyperbolic lines, $L_1$, with ideal points, say, $a_1$ and $b_1$, and $L_2$, with ideal points $a_2$ and $b_2$, such that the ideal points $a_1$, $b_1$, $a_2$, $b_2$ are all distinct.
My question is how to find the geodesic line segment joining the points $p_1 \in L_1$ and $p_2 \in L_2$ which are closest to each other (with respect to the hyperbolic distance, of course). A related question is how to find the center of the circle of which the geodesic line segment is an arc, in the Poincare model of hyperbolic 3-space?
I liked the geometric figure in @MvG's answer in How to find an hyperbolic line that is perpendicular through two other hyperbolic lines?, but this is the planar version of this problem. How do we generalize this geometric approach? For some reason I am struggling a bit with this.

I can explain a solution in the hyperboloid model (which you can then translate to the upper half-space model if you like).

@MoisheKohan, that would be great! Thank you!

OK, later, or maybe somebody else will write an answer first.

no worries. Using the hyperboloid model makes things easier. I am close to a full solution. Thank you for suggesting that!

Yes, the hyperboloid model reduces everything to linear algebra.

I will be using the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic $n$-space, which is  the set $\mathbb H$ of future-directed time-like vectors satisfying
$$
\langle {\mathbf x}, {\mathbf x} \rangle=-1,
$$
where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is a bilinear form of signature $(n,1)$. For a time-like vector ${\mathbf v}$ I define its normalization
$$
\bar {\mathbf v}= \frac{1}{|\mathbf v|} \mathbf v,
$$
where $|\mathbf x|= \sqrt{- \langle {\mathbf x}, {\mathbf x} \rangle}$. Consider two geodesics $h_i, i=1,2$, in  $\mathbb H$, which are intersections of $\mathbb H$ with 2-dimensional linear subspaces $W_i=span(\mathbf u_i, \mathbf v_i)$, where $\mathbf u_i, \mathbf v_i$ are (linearly independent) null-vectors in the future null-cone.
I first work out a condition for orthogonality of two geodesics in $\mathbb H$ meeting at a common point, as is the case for, say, geodesics $h_1$ and $h$. Fix $\mathbf y_1=t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (1-t_1) \mathbf v_1$, $t_1\in (0,1)$, a time-like vector in $W_1$. Then in $W_1$ we find a (space-like) vector $\mathbf y_1^*$ orthogonal to $\mathbf y_1$, given by
$$
\mathbf y_1^*= t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (t_1-1)\mathbf v_1. 
$$
Suppose now that $W$ is the plane spanned by a time-like vector $\mathbf y_1= t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (1-t_1) \mathbf v_1$ (as above) and another time-like vector $\mathbf y_2$. Then the hyperbolic geodesics $h_1, h$ in $\mathbb H$ defined as $h_1=W_1\cap \mathbb H, h=W\cap \mathbb H$, are orthogonal if and only if the vector $\mathbf y_1^*\in W_1$ (Lorentzian-orthogonal to $\mathbf y_1$) is also Lorentzian-orthogonal  to the entire plane $W$, equivalently, is Lorentzian-orthogonal to $\mathbf y_2$. The latter orthogonality condition is
$$
\langle  t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (1-t_1) \mathbf v_1, \mathbf y_2\rangle= 0. 
$$
This gives us a way to compute the hyperbolic geodesic $h$ connecting $h_1, h_2$ orthogonally.
Namely, we search for  vectors  $\mathbf y_i= t_i \mathbf u_i + (1-t_i) \mathbf v_i$,
$t_i\in (0,1)$, $i=1, 2$, satisfying the two equations:
$$
\langle \mathbf y_1^*, \mathbf y_2\rangle= \langle \mathbf y_2^*, \mathbf y_1\rangle=0,
$$
equivalently,
$$
\langle  t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (t_1-1) \mathbf v_1, t_2 \mathbf u_2 + (1-t_2) \mathbf v_2\rangle = \langle  t_2 \mathbf u_2 + (t_2-1) \mathbf v_2, t_1 \mathbf u_1 + (1-t_1) \mathbf v_1\rangle=0. 
$$
Then the common perpendicular segment to $h_1, h_2$ equals $s=\bar{\mathbf y}_1 \bar{\mathbf y}_2\subset \mathbb H$. Searching for vectors $\mathbf y_1, \mathbf y_2$ amounts to solving the above system of two quadratic equations with the unknowns $t_1, t_2$. Of course, the solution does not always exists; it exists if and only if the hyperbolic geodesics $h_1, h_2$ do not intersect in the hyperbolic space and are not "limiting-parallel."
Edit. For solving a system of two quadratic equations, see for instance, here.

@Malkoun: This is an unnatural assumption. I think it amounts to considering the case of two geodesics in a hyperbolic plane, which is easier than the general case.

yes, I think you are right... Let me think a bit more...

@Malkoun: I am not claiming that my solution is optimal; I wrote it awhile ago and just copied it here.

I understand. I appreciate a lot your help. I just think one could possibly do a bit better, using the same approach and ideas (hyperboloid model etc.). I am just trying to see if I can improve a bit what you have done, that's all.

I can think of a fixed point theorem approach to basically numerically solve your system of 2 quadratic equations in $t_1$ and $t_2$. I will phrase it geometrically. Let $(a_0, b_0) \in L_1 \times L_2$ be an "initial guess". Define $(a_n, b_n) = (\overline{p_1(b_{n-1})}, \overline{p_2(a_{n-1}))}$, for $n \geq 1$, where $p_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W_i$, for $i = 1, 2$ and the "bar" on top denotes normalization with respect to the Minkowski inner product.

I think such a sequence may possibly converge to the unique solution, when a unique solution exists (i.e. when $h_1$ and $h_2$ do not intersect in hyperbolic space and are not "limiting-parallel"), assuming the initial guess is close enough to the actual solution.
